# The method Ash() is undefined for the type apples

Tags: java

I'm new to Java or to say precisely programming. I started learning Java by watching Bucky tutorials. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class apples {
     public static void main(String args[]){
         Scanner Ash = new Scanner (System.in);
         System.out.println(Ash());
     } 
}
```

I'm unable to compile this code. I got a message of

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:
>   The method Ash() is undefined for the type apples
>
> at apples.main(apples.java:5)

What does the above message mean? Whatever input i type in keyboard goes to Variable called Ash with help of Scanner. But why Println can't print that value of `Ash()`. But if i use `Ash.nextLine(),` code doesn't give any warmings. If Ash is not defined, then how can Ash.nextLine() is defined?

Comment: `Ash` is a reference of type `Scanner` not a method. i suggest you to learn basic java before getting into `Scanner` etc

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.println(Ash());
```

That considered as a method not a variable.

You might want

```
 System.out.println(Ash);
```

Note that variable names starts with lower case as per naming conventions.

```
 Scanner ash = new Scanner (System.in);
 System.out.println(ash);
```

You might want to go through official java docs in an order. Not just some random tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I forgot to use lower case. I got the message java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]

Comment: that is fine - you are printing out all basic information of "ash" (-> the toString() method is called implicitly in this case). I also suggest what ramanlfc said...try basic java first. Write your own code first without reference to other "foreign" classes.